# how to create parquet partitions with Spark 3.3 and update parquet files every day with new information

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new for Spark overall and for parquet files as well. Please be patient and if you know answer please be specific.
I have s3 bucket which is receiving new csv file every with those columns:

```
["profile", "date", "local_timezone", "utility", "iso", "unit", *[f"hour_{i}" for i in range(24)]
```

My task is to work with ETL jobs and make partitions based on **profile**.
So I did create ETL job, insert that file, and trying to run this:

```
output_df.select("*").write.partitionBy("profile").mode("append")).parquet(s3_output_path).
```

with **append** mode its creating partitions based on profiles:

```
profile=category_one/   
profile=category_two/
```

and adding new parquet file in each of this partitions:

```
part-00000-63df9987-67e4-46bb-b1ef-2fefc1614736.c000.snappy.parquet
```

The problem is that If I process next day csv file, it will create new parquet file and so on.
Even if I will run same date twice, it will create 2 separate parquet files.

I need SAME parquet file to be updated with new data every day, and if there is **profile** and **date** already then whole row should be replaced.

I did try many different options with **overwrite**, **save**. Nothing works. With overwrite, its creating new file, but if i'm tryint to update new rows in data frame its showing me error "File is not existing"

I did also try to modify data frame **output_df** before partitioning and its still not working. Giving all sorts of errors.

So, I just need to run Partitioning every day and update or append data for same partitions in with one parquet file in each partition.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something that deals well with what is known as **UPSERTs** (UPDATE/INSERT). In vanilla Spark, handling UPSERTs  can become increasingly complex and inefficient as your dataset scales. The reason is that Spark's native capabilities don't directly support transactional updates or inserts out-of-the-box.

Thankfully there have been some solutions to this particular problem. Three solutions that right now are very successful are Apache [Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/) , Apache [Hudi](https://hudi.apache.org/) and DataBricks [DeltaLake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html). Out of the 3, I find Iceberg the one that is more useful because of its better AWS integration (but this is more of an opinion so YMMV so do try the other two as you may like them more).

Apache Iceberg excels in this kind of problem that you have by providing robust ACID transaction support, including straightforward `MERGE INTO` operations for **UPSERTs**.

Anyway this is how you would approach this with Iceberg:

You would need to either be able to use `spark.jars.packages` so that the jar that includes the Iceberg functionality is made available OR to provide the needed jar yourself by downloading the right version from [here](https://iceberg.apache.org/releases/). In general in order to have Iceberg work on your system consult this [getting-started](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/getting-started/) guide

Now assuming that you are able to use `spark.jars.packages` (which means you are not working on an air-gapped system) this is how you could approach your problem.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize Spark
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("IcebergMergeExample") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark3-runtime:0.12.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local.type", "hadoop") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse", "s3a://your-bucket/your-iceberg-warehouse/") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create an Iceberg table, if not already existing
spark.sql("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS local.db.table_name (
        profile STRING,
        date STRING,
        local_timezone STRING,
        utility STRING,
        iso STRING,
        unit STRING,
        hour_0 DOUBLE,
        hour_1 DOUBLE,
        ...
        hour_23 DOUBLE
    )
    USING iceberg
    PARTITIONED BY (profile)
""")

# Load new data into a temporary table
new_data_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_new_data")

# Use the MERGE INTO statement that is provided by Iceberg to upsert data
spark.sql("""
    MERGE INTO local.db.table_name AS target
    USING temp_new_data AS source
    ON target.profile = source.profile AND target.date = source.date
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
""")
```

Comment: Hmm, Thanks for the reply. Then what is the logic for doing partitions with parquet files if you can not update/insert data in it? I don't understand. Before I start working with Spark(partitions, parquet) I was expecting that using them will be super easy. The logic is to break daily files in parquet files and use them faster then CSV files. Maybe there is another approach? solution? Maybe I should just **append** parquet files? what is partitioning is for then?

Comment: Indeed, there are performance benefits over flat CSV files when using partitions and Parquet files in Spark, particularly for read-heavy, immutable workloads. However your scenario is different since its a use case requiring frequent updates or inserts. Partitioning helps in read-optimization by reducing data scanned but the problem is that Spark does not natively support UPSERTs.  You need to roll your own way of doing this and as days of data pile up goes one this process becomes slow.Apache Iceberg (and HUDI / DeltaLake in a sense) addresses these gaps for exactly the scenario you have.